# Is there a smart way to pass a class variable using a function?

Tags: python, numpy, class, matplotlib

I have a class to organize my datasets that contains several variables. I read in multiple datasets that's I'd like to compare, so I would like to creat a function that takes one of the class variables as an argument, if that's possible. Currently I have the setup below which I think should work, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant/pythonic way to go about it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input=None):
        _tmp = np.genfromtxt(input)
        self.var1 = _tmp['f0']
        self.var2 = _tmp['f1']
        self.var3 = var1 + var2
        self.var4 = var1 * var2

    def var(self, v='var1'):
        if v=='var1':
            return self.var1
        if v=='var2':
            return self.var2
        if v=='var3':
            return self.var3
        if v=='var4':
            return self.var4

def plot_MyClass(data1, data2, var='var1'):
    plt.plot(data1.var(var), data2.var(var), 'k-')
    return

###########

data1 = MyClass(file1.txt)
data2 = MyClass(file2.txt)
plot_MyClass(data1, data2, var='var3')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's the point of `def var(self, v='var1'):`?? Why not just `data.var1` or `data.var2`?

Comment: You can use `getattr(self, v)`, but then you should consider whether you want 4 separate instance attributes in the first place, or a single `dict`-valued attribute.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In my actual code, I have other details in MyClass that the plotting function requires, so I need to pass the whole object and I wanted an argument to say which of the variables to graph. But you're correct, in the provided code, plt.plot(data1.var1, data2.var2) would work just fine

Comment: @chepner So, I could do away with the "var" function in the class and in my plotting fuction I could just do something like d1 = getattr(data1, var); d2 = getattr(data2, var) ?[sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments]

Comment: @chepner This worked very nicely and is exactly what I was looking for. I just forgot entirely about 'getattr'. If you want to post it as an answer, I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it using a dictionary. There is no special magic required:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input=None):
        _tmp = np.genfromtxt(input)
        # OPTION 1 ===========================
        self.var = {}
        self.var['var1'] = var1 = _tmp['f0']
        self.var['var2'] = var2 = _tmp['f1']
        self.var['var3'] = var3 = var1 + var2
        self.var['var4'] = var4 = var1 * var2
        # And so on...use varX variables from above if needed...
        # OPTION 2 ====================================================
        # The following is identical to option 1, but may be easier to read:
        var1 = _tmp['f0']
        var2 = _tmp['f1']
        self.var = {
            'var1': var1,
            'var2': var2,
            'var3': var1 + var2,
            'var4': var1 * var2
        }


def plot_MyClass(data1, data2, var='var1'):
    plt.plot(data1.var[var], data2.var[var], 'k-')
    return

###########

data1 = MyClass('file1.txt')
data2 = MyClass('file2.txt')
plot_MyClass(data1, data2, var='var3')
plt.show()
```

Note that `var1`, `var2`, etc., in the constructor are just local variables that make it easier to construct your expressions for the different plot variables of interest.

Comment: This is ok, and I will consider it, but would require a fair amount of refactoring to my actual code (already 500 lines). My hack is doing ok, it just doesn't seem like the "right" way to do it